# SHA-256 - mismatch between NodeJS and Java code

Tags: java, node.js, cryptography, sha256

I have this code on Nodejs I need to write similar to Java, but the results differ. I think that the problem is in hex encoding. But I do not understand how it works.

Nodejs code:

```
crypto.createHash('sha256').update(seed, 'hex').digest()
```

Java code:

```
digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] encodedhash = digest.digest(seedString);
```

Comment: How does a typical seed lookalike (is it a string or binary data)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two codes will give you the same output

NodeJS

```
var data = "seed";
var crypto = require('crypto');
crypto.createHash('sha256').update(data).digest("hex");
```

Java

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class SHAHashingExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
    {
        String password = "seed";

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(password.getBytes());

        byte byteData[] = md.digest();

        //convert the byte to hex format method 1
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
         sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }

        System.out.println("Hex format : " + sb.toString());

        //convert the byte to hex format method 2
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0;i<byteData.length;i++) {
            String hex=Integer.toHexString(0xff & byteData[i]);
            if(hex.length()==1) hexString.append('0');
            hexString.append(hex);
        }
        System.out.println("Hex format : " + hexString.toString());
    }
}
```

For more details:

[NodeJS link](https://repl.it/repls/CurvyTatteredMethod) 
[Java link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-sha-hashing-example/)

As pointed out by others it is a matter of how you present data. If in the `update` function you don't specify nothing - like in the solution I gave above - you are telling to interpret the `seed` as encoded with the default UTF-8 encoding. Now what's the translation of UTF-8 string `seed` in hex terms? the answer is `73656564`, as you can easily check for example from [this online tool](https://codebeautify.org/string-hex-converter)

Now let's do a verification. Let's write:

NodeJS

```
var data = "73656564";
crypto.createHash('sha256').update(data, 'hex').digest('hex');
```

You will get the same result as well. You are telling to the `update` function that the data you are providing are an `hex` representation and must be interpreted as such

Hope this can help clarifying the role of `hex`

Comment: In the above example, everything works correctly, but my problem is in the second argument of the update function, namely encoding = hex. If you set the results will be different. And in this my problem I do not understand what does encoding = hex.

Comment: @Павел I improved my answer based on your comment, hope now everything is clearer

Answer (score 0):

From nodejs [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_update_data_inputencoding):

> Updates the hash content with the given data, the encoding of which is
>   given in inputEncoding and can be 'utf8', 'ascii' or 'latin1'. If
>   encoding is not provided, and the data is a string, an encoding of
>   'utf8' is enforced. If data is a Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView, then
>   inputEncoding is ignored.

In simple words it means format of data you are providing.

PS.

Code looks a bit wrong in update you would provide data not a seed.

Comment: The code on nodejs is a sample, it works correctly, the problem is with the code on java. I read the documentation and there is not a word about hex encoding.